# BI Publisher - SQL LIKE statement with parameters in BI Publisher

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher

I have a SQL select statement like below with some parameters; Actually, I want to concatenate some strings with some parameters:
N.B : It works correctly in Oracle sql developer, but when I want to execute it in BI Publisher! an error **ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended** 
appears !
Is there any difference between the templates (In term of parameter concatenation)?
Any suggestions?
Thanks,

```
select 
col1 as column1,
col2 as column2
from mytable
where col1 like  :Param1 || '%' || :Param2 || '%str%'
```

Comment: How do you use this query in BI ? Can you give us more details ?

Comment: @VBoka I use it to fill a List of Values !

Comment: @VBoka more details like?

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
col1 as column1,
col2 as column2
from mytable
where col1 like  '%' + @param + '%' or col1 like '%
```

That would be the MSSQL